# JSON Lint validated JSON String but the same doesnt gets parsed with JS

Tags: javascript, java, json

I have built a Automation Test Framework using TestNG + Selenium where I am generating a HTML Report at the end of the execution.

I am passing the execution details directly as JSON string (as we are not hosting the report into a webserver, this is a local setup) within the HTML file and running an internal JS to populated the data into the report grid.

Everything is working fine, except that once I get an exception I am trying to report the stacktrace in HTML which again gets into the report as a JSON value and JS denies to parse it.

To the understand the problem better, please check the code snippet below

// This is where I am reporting the exception

```
public static void ReportException(Exception e){
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);  
    BuildReport(itrStepCnt,"Exception Occurred!",StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson("Exception Details - "+sw.toString()),"ERROR",captureScreenshot());
    ItrConcludeReport();
}
```

and the converting a map to JSON String and finally reporting to HTML

```
content = content.replaceAll("@testrepdt@",finalContent);
```

JS is trying to parse it as following and fails to do the samr

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse(dt);
```

Here is the JSON String which gets validated with Lint but didnt gets passed through JSON Parser

```
[
{
    "testclasspath": "app.applicationa.testcases.module1",
    "testcasename": "TC004",
    "executiontime": "5799ms",
    "teststatus": "PASS",
    "iteration": [
        {
            "teststeps": [
                {
                    "Status": "PASS",
                    "Description": "pass desc",
                    "StepNo": "1",
                    "StepName": "StepName 1:1",
                    "Snapshot": "./SNAPSHOTS/15_Nov_2015_020306095_73350.png"
                }
            ],
            "itrname": "Iteration: 1"
        },
        {
            "teststeps": [
                {
                    "Status": "PASS",
                    "Description": "pass desc",
                    "StepNo": "1",
                    "StepName": "StepName 1:2",
                    "Snapshot": "./SNAPSHOTS/15_Nov_2015_020306291_46233.png"
                }
            ],
            "itrname": "Iteration: 2"
        },
        {
            "teststeps": [
                {
                    "Status": "PASS",
                    "Description": "pass desc",
                    "StepNo": "1",
                    "StepName": "StepName 1:3",
                    "Snapshot": "./SNAPSHOTS/15_Nov_2015_020306481_36460.png"
                }
            ],
            "itrname": "Iteration: 3"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "testclasspath": "app.applicationa.testcases.module1",
    "testcasename": "TC002",
    "executiontime": "6025ms",
    "teststatus": "PASS",
    "iteration": [
        {
            "teststeps": [
                {
                    "Status": "PASS",
                    "Description": "pass desc",
                    "StepNo": "1",
                    "StepName": "StepName 1:3",
                    "Snapshot": "Not Required"
                },
                {
                    "Status": "ERROR",
                    "Description": "Exception Details - java.lang.NullPointerException\\r\\n\\tat app.applicationa.testcases.module1.TC002(module1.java:64)\\r\\n\\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\\r\\n\\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\\r\\n\\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\\r\\n\\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)\\r\\n\\tat org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)\\r\\n",
                    "StepNo": "1",
                    "StepName": "Exception Occurred!",
                    "Snapshot": "./SNAPSHOTS/null"
                }
            ],
            "itrname": "Iteration : 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: What's the JSON parse error? Should be in the console.

Comment: the json string must start with { and end with } . or did you just forget to put them in your question ?

Comment: @Tahar: yes I forgot tof include in the question.

Comment: @Kenney: I forgot to mention that I am new to JS and JSON, so I m not sure how to find the parse error.Which console you are talking about, do we have an option  to catch JS exception and debug it??

Comment: Just pres F12 in your browser; there's a console there. You could do `console.log( JSON.parse( dt ) );` in your script and it would show up there (after you reload the page).

Comment: don't forget that JSON.parse(jsonString) takes a string as parameter. So your dt is it a string or a json object ?